# jQuery's get() not properly returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have a very simple code that when the document is ready it tries to get some data using jQuery's get():

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        startGetting();
    });

    function startGetting(){
        console.log("entering");
        $.get('prediction.pl', function(data){
            console.log(data)
        });

    }
```

My expected results on the console are:

```
entering
>data
```

but for some reason no `data` is being returned or anything.

If I execute the get() function straight in the console it does print out `data`. Any ideas why it doesn't work when called from the code, but does work when run from the console?

EDIT:

I noticed that if I change startGetting() to:

```
 function startGetting(){
        console.log("entering");
        foo=$.get('prediction.pl', function(data){
            console.log(data)
        });
  console.log(foo);
  }
```

Now `foo` has the data I want.
But I have no idea why is this happening, any ideas?

Comment: Do you see your "entering" message on the console?

Comment: Yea I do. But if I put something in the callback function, say console.log("in callback"), that doesn't get run.

Comment: If there is other code besides this, you may have an error somewhere else. Try putting just this code in code, without anything else. You should also have an error handler - perhaps the get() is failing for some reason - without the error handler, you won't see it.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Have you called `jQuery.noConflict()`? I notice you use `jQuery(document).ready()` with `$` as the parameter to your callback, but then you use `$.get()` within `startGetting()`...

Comment: No errors. The use of 'jQuery(document).ready()' was arbitrary. Just checked using '$(document).ready()' and same problem happens.

Comment: Can you add error handling to your get? E.g. `$.get("prediction.pl", function(data) {
    console.log("success:"+data);
  })
  .success(function() { console.log("second success"); })
  .error(function() { console.log("error"); })
  .complete(function() { console.log("complete"); });`